# How to retrieve already created (graph) database in Cassandra through gremlin?

Tags: database, cassandra, graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I have already created a graph in Titan using gremlin and stored in Cassandra.
In Gremlin,

```
graph = TitanFactory.open("conf/titan-cassandra.properties");
tx = graph.newTransaction();
saturn= tx.addVertex(T.label, "titan", "name", "saturn", "age", 10000);

tx.commit();
```

Let's suppose I want to connect to Cassandra and retrieve the data ( "e.g. how many vertices in graph", How do I connect & query Cassandra?

Answer (score 2):

You should do everything through the Graph and Gremlin APIs.

```
gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open("conf/titan-cassandra.properties"); // open Cassandra-backed graph
gremlin> g = graph.traversal() // create a graph traversal source
gremlin> g.V().count() // get the vertex count
gremlin> graph.close() // close the graph
```

You should go through the Graph/Gremlin APIs instead of using a Cassandra driver to do a direct connection to the Titan keyspace and tables. If you attempt to do that, you would see that the values are just blobs. This is because [Titan data model](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/data-model.html) uses a custom serialization representation to store data into Cassandra (or any other supported backend).

I'd highly recommend reading the [Getting Started](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/getting-started.html) documentation for Titan as well as the [TinkerPop3](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/) documentation on the Gremlin query language. I also recommend taking advantage of the active Google Groups for [Titan](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/aureliusgraphs) and [TinkerPop](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gremlin-users).